# how to make python script process all files if it takes only one?

Tags: python, shell

I have a python script that takes 1 wav file and produces a shorter version of it.

```
python process_wav.py 1.wav
```

Doing `python process_wav.py *.wav` does not work.

Comment: Can we see your code so that we can help you?

Comment: Hi @ERJAN, please show us your code.

Comment: You could catch the argument *.wav and then load all files in the directory instead.

Comment: @Sri The shell expands wildcards, the program never sees `*.wav`

Answer (score 2):

Use a shell loop:

```
for file in *.wav
do
    python process_wav.py "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the argument in your Python script, say `testing.py`, and use `glob` to expand it:

```
import sys, glob

def glob_files(glob_pattern):
    return glob.glob(glob_pattern)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    glob_pattern = sys.argv[1]
    print(glob_files(glob_pattern))
```

When you call it you must escape the `*`:

```
python3 testing.py \*.wav
```